# update redirection ASP .net

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I a problem with my site..
There is a logo in my site thats redirect to the Home page.
The problem is that if for example i'm in page `www.domain.com/about` and I press the logo - everything fine and it goes to `www.domain.com/Main`, but if i'm in page `www.domain.com/page/125` It's redirect me to `www.domain.com/page/Main` instead of `www.domain.com/Main`.
I have all the site files. which file I should change?
Is it the sitemap?
(I have no page name `page` or `125`...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how your project is structured or if you're using WebForms or MVC, it's difficult for the StackOverflow community to help you. Please update your question with more details if the below suggestion doesn't help or apply.

If you're using using WebForms with MasterPage and content pages, the logo is usually in the MasterPage e.g. Site.Master

Try and find something like this in your Site.Master

```
<a href="Main"><img src="logo.gif"/></a>
```

and replace it with this

```
<a href="/Main"><img src="logo.gif"/></a>
```

or this

```
<a runat="server" href="Main"><img src="logo.gif"/></a>
```